# SET operator use in mysql. Explanation?

Tags: mysql

Allright, i see that without 1st line, the second query will not work. But I don't understand why. Why its not working without SET? What set does mean ?

```
$query = "update messages set $name=$name+1 where id='$idd'";
$db->setQuery( $query );
$db->query( $query ) or die('blogai');

$query2 = "select up,down from messages where id='$idd'";
$db->setQuery( $query2 );
$db->query( $query2 ) or die('blogai');
```

Comment: These two queries have nothing in common other than a [gaping SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're not escaping those variables, this is reckless programming that will get you burned.

Comment: yeah, but if i remove first query, ajax voting stops to work

Comment: If you still don't understand how to properly escape your SQL variables, you should stop what you're doing right now and spend some time reading up on that. You're digging yourself a deep hole that could end up getting you into extremely serious trouble.

Comment: Hey Aelios. I just left query with SET. Didn't really understood what u meant using query editor?

Answer (score 0):

Check your sql request in your database query editor :

```
select up,down from messages where id='yourValue'
```

Comment: how did this differ from `select up,down from messages where id='$idd'`?

Comment: Because I talk about Database query editor (so no php variable)